# Oracle total row

Tags: oracle

I'm having a brain fart and I can't seem to push past it.  I've done this before but I can't remember how I did it.  Here's the gist:  I have a table I created (test) and in this table I'm storing some random information. (It's a test table and so the information in the table is not applicable to anything).  My test table looks like this:

```
Name     varchar2 Primary key
age      varchar2
sex      char 
social   varchar2  Primary Key
```

I'm using this table as an example and that is why I have the two primary keys.  I was showing a student how to do a composite key.

My question is this:  how do I create a query that has a total count at the end of the rows?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
Name   Male  Female
xxxxx   m
xxxxx   m
xxxxx   m
xxxxx   m
xxxxx          F
xxxxx          F
Total:  4      2
```

I created the following query (which doesn't quite work) just as a test.

```
set feedback on    
compute sum(COUNT(SEX)) LABEL "# of males" of sex_count on report 
select count(sex) as sex_count
from test
where sex = upper('m')
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this resolve your problem?

```
select name, male, female from (
    select name, 
           decode( sex, 'm', 'm', null) Male, 
           decode( sex, 'f', 'f', null) Female, 0 n 
      from test
     union
    select 'Total', 
           to_char(sum(decode(sex, 'm', 1, 0))), 
           to_char(sum(decode(sex, 'f', 1, 0))), 
           1 
      from test
     group by 'Total' 
  ) order by n
```

Link to Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e501/3/0

Comment: It could, but I remember using the compute function above the query.   I feel like I'm just making it harder than it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the "compute...on report" statement, it looks like you're using SQL*Plus.  Try this:

```
compute count label total of male female on report
break on report

 select name, decode(sex, 'm', sex) male, decode(sex, 'f', sex) female
  from test
 order by name;
```